# how to get content between special string with shell awk or sed?

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

i've a file contain following content:

```
(visible:true)
url(http://style.ep.com/image/control/flash1-tab.gif)
<img src="http://img1.ep.com/4667/product/s-50f8f86cf0822.jpg.jpg" alt="god">
<script src="http://img1.ep.com/4667/codeFromLink.js"></script>
```

i want to get content between url( and ), also src=" and ",result as following:

```
http://style.ep.com/image/control/flash1-tab.gif
http://img1.ep.com/4667/product/s-50f8f86cf0822.jpg.jpg
http://img1.ep.com/4667/codeFromLink.js
```

i've used follow:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS=")";FS="("}NF>1{print $NF}' $file_obj
awk 'BEGIN{RS=" ";FS="src=\""}NF>1{print($NF)}' $file_obj |sed 's/\"//g'
```

but i got:

```
visible:true
http://style.ep.com/image/control/flash1-tab.gif
http://img1.ep.com/4667/product/s-50f8f86cf0822.jpg.jpg
http://img1.ep.com/4667/codeFromLink.js></script>
```

how to?
thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Very short grep solution:

```
grep -Po '(url\(|src=")\K[^")]*' "$file_obj"
```

You can read about `\K` [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Extended-Patterns).

Or a bit longer, but safer:

```
grep -Po 'url\(\K[^)]*|src="\K[^"]*' "$file_obj"
```

Comment: +1, but note that `-P` (for Perl-compatible regular expressions) is a _GNU_ `grep` extension (won't work on FreeBSD/OSX, for instance). Also, there is a chance this will break, given that `)` is a valid character in a URL (though rarely used).

Comment: @mklement0 Good point. I have updated my answer with a bit safer solution.

Comment: Unfortunately, the updated version won't work either (try with `url(http://style.ep.com/image/control/flash1(-)tab.gif)`. Here's what would work, using a _positive lookahead_: `grep -Po '(url\(|src=")\K[^\s]+(?=[")])'`

Answer (score 0):

Try `grep`  with `-oP` parameters,

```
$ grep -oP '(?<=url\()[^)]*|(?<=src=\")[^"]*' file
http://style.ep.com/image/control/flash1-tab.gif
http://img1.ep.com/4667/product/s-50f8f86cf0822.jpg.jpg
http://img1.ep.com/4667/codeFromLink.js
```

Through awk,

```
$ awk -F\( '/^url/{sub(/.$/,"",$2); print $2}/src=/{split($0,a,"\""); print a[2]}' file
http://style.ep.com/image/control/flash1-tab.gif
http://img1.ep.com/4667/product/s-50f8f86cf0822.jpg.jpg
http://img1.ep.com/4667/codeFromLink.js
```

Comment: url_str=`grep -Eo "url\((.+?)\)" $file_obj | sed -E "s|url\(||g" | sed -E "s|\)||g"`
    src_str=`grep -Eo "src=\"(.+?)\"" $file_obj | sed -E "s|src=\"||g" | sed -E "s|\"||g"`

i fix it.
 thanks avinash raj

Comment: @user3818534 You should accept the answer by clicking the check mark. That should give credit to the one who helped you.

Comment: You can simplify it by using ``\K``

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sed -r -n -e 's/url\(([^)]+).*/\1/p' file
http://style.ep.com/image/control/flash1-tab.gif

$ sed -r -n -e 's/.*src="([^"]+).*/\1/p' file
http://img1.ep.com/4667/product/s-50f8f86cf0822.jpg.jpg
http://img1.ep.com/4667/codeFromLink.js

$ sed -r -n -e 's/url\(([^)]+).*/\1/p' -e 's/.*src="([^"]+).*/\1/p' file
http://style.ep.com/image/control/flash1-tab.gif
http://img1.ep.com/4667/product/s-50f8f86cf0822.jpg.jpg
http://img1.ep.com/4667/codeFromLink.js
```

Comment: You can join the `sed` like this `sed -rne 's/url\(([^)]+).*/\1/p;s/.*src="([^"]+).*/\1/p'` using `;`, and compress the options parameter to  `-rne`

Answer (score 0):

A streamlined `awk` solution:

```
awk -F'url\\(|\\)|src="|"' 'length($2) {print $2}' file
```

- `-F'url\\(|\\)|src="|"'` defines a *regular expression* to use as *field separators* (stored in reserved variable `FS`, which the `-F` command-line option sets), effectively comprising the following tokens:

  - `url(`
  - `)`
  - `src="`
  - `"`
  - Note the required *double-backslash escaping* of `(` and `)`.

    - `awk`'s *general* string parsing interprets `\` escape sequences in a first pass, so the `\\` tells it that a literal `\` should become part of the resulting regular expression, so that the regex engine sees, for instance, `\(`, i.e.: a `(` character that should be taken *literally* (rather than starting a capture group).
- Splitting each line uses these tokens as field separators puts the URL into the 2nd field, `$2`.
- Since not all input lines contain a URL, pattern `length($2)` (implied: `length($2) > 0`) ensures that the print command, `{print $2}`, is only executed for lines where a URL is found.

*Caveat*: Won't work with URLs that have embedded `)` characters, but that's rare in practice.
To fix this, use the following instead:

```
awk -F'url\\(|\\)([[:blank:]]|$)|src="|"' 'length($2) {print $2}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another `gnu awk` (gnu due to `RS` containing multiple characters)

```
awk -v RS="http" -F'[")]' 'NR>1{print RS$1}' file
http://style.ep.com/image/control/flash1-tab.gif
http://img1.ep.com/4667/product/s-50f8f86cf0822.jpg.jpg
http://img1.ep.com/4667/codeFromLink.js
```